# Java Programming for sorting an array

Tags: java, arrays

I have attended an Interview Yesterday, I don't find the solution of an given problem below.
How to sort an int array with starting 3 digits numbers and remaining 2,1,4,5 etc digits.

Ex:-Input is

```
i={1,34,323,456,5432,34566,33,45,654}
```

output is,

```
i={323,456,654,1,34,33,45,5432}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that one might wish to the alter the order of the number of digits, and allow them to be specified in any order. So I have a "sort" array that corresponds to the number of digits that should be processed. I also assumed that one should sort the values in increasing order within the final array. I also thought that the sorting was part of the experiment, so I did not use Arrays.sort.

Here is my take on the approach:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int[] arr = {1,34,323,456,5432,34566,33,45,654};
    int[] sort = {3, 2, 1, 4, 5 };

    int lastPos = 0;
    int loopPos = 0;
    int[] output = new int[arr.length];
    // process the whole array
    for (int s = 0; s < sort.length; ++s) {
        String fmt = String.format("^[0-9]{%d}$", sort[s]);
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile(fmt);            

        // set to end of the current location
        loopPos = lastPos;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
            int val = arr[i];
            Matcher m = pat.matcher(Integer.toString(val));
            if (m.matches()) {
                // start at the beginning of the loopPos
                // continue until lastPos
                if (lastPos == loopPos) {
                    output[lastPos++] = val;
                }
                else {
                    for (int ins = loopPos; ins < lastPos; ++ins) {
                        int atPos = output[ins];
                        // if we are smaller, must insert before
                        if (val <= atPos) {
                            for (int rev = lastPos; rev > loopPos; --rev) {
                                output[rev] = output[rev - 1];
                            }
                            output[ins] = val;
                            ++lastPos;
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (val > atPos) {
                            output[lastPos++] = val;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        } //i
    } //s

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(output));
}
```

Sample result:

> [323, 456, 654, 33, 34, 45, 1, 5432, 34566]

Answer (score 0):

This my look silly,but you can do this:

Multipy every element that is not 3 digit long by 1000.
Sort the array.
Divide by 1000 everything that is not 3 digits long.

Comment: Beware numeric overflow.

Comment: I was just going for the simpliest thing. Anyways, you are right beacuse my suggestion does not work for numbers that have more than 7 digits. @Andreas

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to sort by length, first convert `int[]` to `String[]`. You can then sort the `String[]` using a `Comparator`.

For sorting, first sort by length, then by value. Since your primary sort is by length, a simple string comparison is fine for the secondary sort by value.

As for the weird sort order of 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, you are basically flipping the values 1 and 3. One simple way to do that is to say `4 - x` when `1 <= x <= 3`, i.e. 1, 2, 3 becomes 3, 2, 1.

So, here is the code.

```
public static void sort321(int ... intArray) {
    String[] strArray = new String[intArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
        if (intArray[i] < 0)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Negative numbers not allowed: " + intArray[i]);
        strArray[i] = Integer.toString(intArray[i]);
    }
    Arrays.sort(strArray, (s1, s2) -> {
        int len1 = (s1.length() <= 3 ? 4 - s1.length() : s1.length());
        int len2 = (s2.length() <= 3 ? 4 - s2.length() : s2.length());
        int cmp = Integer.compare(len1, len2);
        if (cmp == 0)               // comment to remove secondary sort
            cmp = s1.compareTo(s2); // comment to remove secondary sort
        return cmp;
    });
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
}
```

**TEST**

```
sort321(1,34,323,456,5432,34566,33,45,654);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[323, 456, 654, 33, 34, 45, 1, 5432, 34566]
```

---

That is not what you showed as the expected result, however I believe this is what you wanted. You could drop the secondary sort by commenting the marked lines, in which case you'd get:

```
[323, 456, 654, 34, 33, 45, 1, 5432, 34566]
```

where `34` and `33` are reversed.

---

Now, to get closer to the result you specified, the requirement to sort length in order 3, 2, 1, 4, ... is wrong, and you might have meant to simply sort length 3 first, i.e. order 3, 1, 2, 4, ...

If that is the case, change a 3 to a 0, i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4 becomes 1, 2, 0, 4.

Also removing the secondary sort will then get the displayed result, except it still includes that missing number: `34566`.

```
public static void sort3first(int ... intArray) {
    String[] strArray = new String[intArray.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++)
        strArray[i] = Integer.toString(intArray[i]);
    Arrays.sort(strArray, (s1, s2) -> Integer.compare((s1.length() == 3 ? 0 : s1.length()),
                                                      (s2.length() == 3 ? 0 : s2.length())));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[323, 456, 654, 1, 34, 33, 45, 5432, 34566]
```